# presentPopoverFromRect from a button goes out of bounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

So I am using [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover/) to display a custom view controller pop up. I have a UIView in which inside it has another UIView called containerView. Inside this containerView, I have a UIButton. This is where I wanted to present my popover from. So here's what I did:

```
  [self.popoverDialog presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.containerView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

The issue is that the arrow and everything is showing from this button, but the popover goes out of self.containerView bounds. How can I make it so that the popover is displayed within the containerView bounds?

**EDIT:**

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here it is:
The light gray is the containerView I mentioned above. THe popover theoretically should be shown within that light gray bounds not going outside.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the view that is contained inside the popover, go to it's view controller and set it's property contentSizeForViewInPopover. Here you can set the size so that it fits the bounds of your containerView.

OP wants to position the popover so that it only shows up in his container view. I found this bit of code in the WEPopoverController.m file

```
- (void)repositionPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect
                       inView:(UIView *)theView
     permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections {

CGRect displayArea = [self displayAreaForView:theView];
WEPopoverContainerView *containerView = (WEPopoverContainerView *)self.view;
[containerView updatePositionWithAnchorRect:rect
                                displayArea:displayArea
                   permittedArrowDirections:arrowDirections];

popoverArrowDirection = containerView.arrowDirection;
containerView.frame = [theView convertRect:containerView.frame toView:backgroundView];
```

}

You could possibly call this method and it might reposition your popover so that it is now inside your container viw.

Comment: I already did that.. the size is fine.. but just want to keep it with that size, such that it doesnt go out of bounds

Comment: Could you provide an image? I am having trouble understanding what you mean by going out of bounds. Is it still entirely inside the screen?

Comment: Ah that make sense. So what you could do is instead of presenting the popover from the frame of the sender, you can create a CGRect that is off set. The problem is that the popover's arrow comes from it's center. I am trying to look for a way that you can do this offset and have the arrow be more to the right. Do you know if there's a method in WEPopover that has that?

Comment: Hmm...I don't think there is any that does that. I actually did create that CGRect instead of presenting it from the sender, but as you mentioned the arrow is not at the right place

Comment: I found this in the documentation of WEPopover "Support for limiting the area to display the popover: implement the protocol WEPopoverParentView for the view you supply to the presentPopover method and implement the - (CGRect)displayAreaForPopover." Maybe you could try it out.

Comment: I am not sure how I would use that to solve my issue? How do I make so that my view/container view conforms to this protocol?

Comment: Hmm. I thought it might allow you to limit where the popover can be shown on your screen but maybe not. I am currently reading through the WEPopoverContainerView.m file (https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover/blob/master/Classes/Popover/WEPopoverContainerView.m). One thing you could do is change some of the variables like the arrowRect. But that is hardly a complete and efficient answer.

Comment: Also found a method that I have added to my answer. See if you can call that method and set the rect to where you want to reposition your popover.